# How to set the limit for key and value for the Python Program

Tags: python, list, dictionary, self, ordereddictionary

How to set the limit for the key and value for the below program. I wrote one python function to add key and values. How to limit the number of keys = 3 and values = 4. Need to ignore the more than 3 keys and 4 values are added.

Is there any thing like below given in program

```
self.size_key = 3
and self.size_value = 4 or [[] for _ in range(5)]
```

sample code

```
class my_dict(dict):    
    def add(self, key, value):
        #if len(value) < 4 and len(key) < 3:
            self.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

    def remove_key(self, key):
        del self[key]

    def remove_value(self, key, value):
        if value in self[key]:
            self[key].remove(value)

dict_obj = my_dict()
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value1')
dict_obj.add('key2', 'value9')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value3')
print(dict_obj)
```

Comment: Can you please explain better what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: if I add more than 5 values  for key1, still my key1 shows only 4 values

Comment: if i try to add more than 4 keys,  still my dictionary shows only 3 keys

Comment: Why? Are you trying to create a cache of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you would need to use an Ordered Dict.  Because dicts do not keep an order outside of a list.  It would be impossible to predict which key is getting deleted.

This solves your problem.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class my_dict(OrderedDict):
    def add(self, key, value):
        self.check(key)
        self.setdefault(key, []).append(value)

    def check(self, key):
        if len(self.keys()) == 3:
            del self[next(iter(self))]
        if len(self.get(key, [])) == 4:
            del self[key][0]

dict_obj = my_dict()
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value1')
dict_obj.add('key2', 'value9')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value3')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value4')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value5')
dict_obj.add('key1', 'value6')
dict_obj.add('key3', 'value6')
dict_obj.add('key4', 'value6')
print(dict_obj)
```